# How do i repopulate my listview in TabHosts?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-activity

I want to be able to restart an activity when a user clicks a button. Most importantly after I restart, I want the tab hosts & tabs to still display.

**Issue:**
Currently, when I restart an activity, the tab host & tabs disappears, after recreation. 


I have researched this issue heavily, however the complex nature of my code is challenging, and other answers were not helpful for my case.

## Code & Current approach taken so far:

### I have four tabs created using tabHost:

**INBOX_SPEC**    -  InboxActivity Class 
**OUTBOX_SPEC**   - OutActivity Clas s
**PROFILE_SPEC**  - ProfileActivity Class  
**LPGA_SPEC**    - LPGAActivity Class 

Within **InboxActivity** Class, when a user clicks a button I want to restart the InboxActivity.

### **Code:   InboxActivity Class:**

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View v)
      {

          finish();
           Intent intent = getIntent();
          //destroyActivity(intent);
         startActivity(intent);
           // Intent refresh = new Intent();
           // startActivity(refresh);//Start the same Activity
           // finish(); //finish Activity.

         // InboxActivity.refreshContent();

      }
    });
```

### **Code:  Creating Tabhost in TabAndListView Class:**

```
   TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    getActionBar().hide();

    // Inbox Tab
    TabSpec inboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(INBOX_SPEC);
    // Tab Icon
    inboxSpec.setIndicator(INBOX_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_inbox));
    Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, InboxActivity.class);
    // Tab Content
    inboxSpec.setContent(inboxIntent);

    // Outbox Tab
    TabSpec outboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(OUTBOX_SPEC);
    outboxSpec.setIndicator(OUTBOX_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_outbox));
    Intent outboxIntent = new Intent(this, OutboxActivity.class);
    outboxSpec.setContent(outboxIntent);

    // Profile Tab
    TabSpec profileSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(PROFILE_SPEC);
    profileSpec.setIndicator(PROFILE_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_profile));
    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
    profileSpec.setContent(profileIntent);

    // LPGA_SPEC Tab
    TabSpec LPGASpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(LPGA_SPEC);
    LPGASpec.setIndicator(LPGA_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_profile));
    Intent LPGAIntent = new Intent(this, WomenActivity.class);
    LPGASpec.setContent(LPGAIntent);



    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(inboxSpec); // Adding Inbox tab
    tabHost.addTab(outboxSpec); // Adding Outbox tab
    tabHost.addTab(profileSpec); // Adding Profile tab
    tabHost.addTab(LPGASpec); // Adding Profile tab
}
```

Comment: hi, did you try recreate();

Comment: I tired there but I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can only be called on top-level activity

Comment: ohhh. why do you want to restart it anyways?

Comment: See in each Activity, I create a Hashmap for ListView, I make a a HTTP Request, parse JSON data, and add  HashList to ArrayList, for displaying JSON data in a Listview. Basically each tab activity contains a code to pull in data. I wanted to create a button to reload, my list view data, So i need to parse in new JSON each time

Comment: then my suggestion is put that sequence of process in a single method.. then whenever you want to refresh your data.. just call that method.. i bet you are using AsyncTask for it right..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84419/discussion-between-sarah-boland-and-sheychan).

Comment: As I can see in your code All you have to do is put another LoadInbox.execute(); on your onClickListener

Comment: Do you mean?  public void onClick(View v)
          {
          //  finish();
            new LoadInbox().execute(); }

Comment: yes and i want to know the result

Comment: The dialog loading screen appears now, but the results in the listview remain the same, the list view does not update.

Comment: coz maybe it has no changes in the server???

Comment: Oh it works!! thank you so much!! xx Is there a way to clear the old listview items so the newly parsed data is only on the listview. At the moment the json items are getting added onto the older list of items.

Comment: Maybe set  inboxList = null; within the onClick before the execute

Comment: in onPreExecute(); inside your AsyncTask.. try listview.removeAllViews(); to prevent repetition of your data

Comment: I'm getting listview cannot be resolved

Answer (score 1):

You just to rerun the code where you have populated your ListView in your:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
  public void onClick(View v)
  {

      //Rerun the code where you populate the listView here

  }
});
```

Then make sure the listview has been reset before repopulating

Comment: Sorry I'm confused with the listview.removeAllViews section in onPreExecute, I'm not sure what to do there to reset before repopulating